# Monitoring not showing all pipeline runs

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my Azure Data Factory, Monitoring appears to only be showing pipeline activity that was kicked off via a schedule. I've executed a number of pipelines manually. Those don't appear to be showing up in Monitoring. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Any pipelines executed either via Powershell or any other means should show up in list of running pipelines. Did you check if any filters are in place? There is date filter by default. Or sorted incorrectly?

Comment: @SumitB - I'm not talking about "running pipelines". I'm talking about pipelines that have already executed. The only ones showing up are ones executed via a schedule. This is not a sorting issue or filter issue. They are simply not showing up.

Comment: Did you trigger it? Or just use debug button? Only trigger ones will show out in monitor

Comment: @FangLiu - That's what's happening. If you want to make this into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And for debug, you don’t need publish your changes. But for trigger, you have to publish your changes, otherwise, it won’t take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only trigger ones will show out in monitor. Debug runs will just show in output of authoring tab and it can’t be accessed after you close that tab.

Updated:
ADF supports view active debug runs now.
[image]